# Can someone explain to use .change on select elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, onchange

I need to run a script only if a certain select has been changed. (There are five selects) I'm using jquery. Anyone know?

Comment: You have the answer in your title.  `.change`.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to "run a script" at the moment when the select changes, i.e., as an immediate response to the change, or that you want to be able to detect later whether it has changed? You mention there are five selects but you only want this functionality for one of them - are you having trouble restricting it to the one, or...? Please show the code you've tried so far...

Comment: ok. i didnt know that was how the .change() worked. Thanks for all the answers. As condescending as they may be.

Comment: That's what the documentation is for: http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.change()` event is called when the input element is changed:

```
$(':input').change(function() {
  // I changed. Now what?
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Select the required `select` element by giving it a unique id or class name and attach `change` event handler to only that.

Some thing like this

```
<select>..</select>
<select>..</select>
<select>..</select>
<select id="iNeedToBeChanged">..</select>
<select>..</select>
```

Js

```
$('#iNeedToBeChanged').change(function(){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$('select[name=example]').change(function() {
  // Do things.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You question is a bit confusing. Do you have 5 seperate  or a select with 5 options?

if you are just wanting to run code when a certain select has changed then this will work.

```
$("#selectId").change(function() {
    // your code goes here...
});
```

if you are wanting to know if a certain option was selected then this will work.

```
$("#selectId").change(function() {
    if($("select option:selected").text() == "Option 4") {

        // your code goes here...
    }
});
```

even more info can be found here - http://api.jquery.com/change/